# Flask SQLAlchemy Won't Create Record (DateTimeField)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm putting together a CRM, and I'm having a little trouble. Everything has been working just fine, until I tried passing a time with a DateTimeField with SQLAlchemy. Prior to adding the time field, the record would create and add to the database without any issues. After, however, I the record simply wouldn't create. The page would reload, and I'd have no validation errors. I've been plugging away at it, and I've finally received an error. All of the data is passing through fine, except the time. The time is being fed through as `<wtforms.fields.core.DateTimeField object at 0x10fe67210>`. How do I get around this issue? I feel like the solution is simple, and I'm going to feel dumb for not seeing it sooner. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the entire error log:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError
sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input.
[SQL: INSERT INTO tours (customer_fname, customer_lname, customer_phone, partner_fname, partner_lname, partner_phone, region, tour_date, tour_time, gift, timestamp, user_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: [{'user_id': 1, 'partner_phone': 'jkljlkj', 'tour_time': <wtforms.fields.core.DateTimeField object at 0x10fe67210>, 'partner_lname': 'jkljlk', 'region ... (34 characters truncated) ... ': 'kljklj', 'gift': 'Cruise', 'customer_lname': 'lkjlk', 'customer_phone': 'jkljl', 'partner_fname': 'jlkjlk', 'timestamp': None, 'tour_date': None}]]

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1173, in _execute_context
context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 808, in _init_compiled
param.append(processors[key](compiled_params[key]))
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py", line 759, in process
"SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python "
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2463, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2449, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1866, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 272, in decorated_view
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/Desktop/BlueSkyAdmin/app/routes.py", line 68, in new_tour
db.session.commit()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1036, in commit
self.transaction.commit()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 503, in commit
self._prepare_impl()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 482, in _prepare_impl
self.session.flush()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2479, in flush
self._flush(objects)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2617, in _flush
transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 153, in reraise
raise value
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2577, in _flush
flush_context.execute()
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 422, in execute
rec.execute(self)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 589, in execute
uow,
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 245, in save_obj
insert,
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1137, in _emit_insert_statements
statement, params
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 982, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 293, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1101, in _execute_clauseelement
distilled_params,
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1176, in _execute_context
e, util.text_type(statement), parameters, None, None
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1476, in _handle_dbapi_exception
util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 398, in raise_from_cause
reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 152, in reraise
raise value.with_traceback(tb)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1173, in _execute_context
context = constructor(dialect, self, conn, *args)
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 808, in _init_compiled
param.append(processors[key](compiled_params[key]))
File "/Users/brandoncarr/.local/share/virtualenvs/BlueSkyAdmin-PG_RBAa1/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/sqlite/base.py", line 759, in process
"SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python "
```

My view:

```
@app.route('/tours/new', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def new_tour():
    form = ToursForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        tours = Tours(customer_fname=form.customer_fname.data, customer_lname=form.customer_lname.data, 
        partner_fname=form.partner_fname.data, partner_lname=form.partner_lname.data, 
        customer_phone=form.customer_phone.data, partner_phone=form.partner_phone.data, 
        region=form.region.data, gift=form.gift.data, tour_time=form.tour_time, author=current_user)
        db.session.add(tours)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Tour has been created', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('tours'))
    return render_template('create-tour.html', title='Create A New Tour', form=form)
```

My model:

```
class Tours(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer_fname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer_lname = db.Column(db.String(50))
    customer_phone = db.Column(db.String(140))
    partner_fname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    partner_lname = db.Column(db.String(100))
    partner_phone = db.Column(db.String(100))
    region = db.Column(db.String(140))
    tour_date = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    tour_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)
    gift = db.Column(db.String())
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Tours {}>'.format(self.customer_fname, self.customer_lname, self.customer_phone, 
        self.partner_fname, self.partner_lname, self.partner_phone, self.region, self.tour_date, 
        self.tour_time, self.gift, self.timestamp)
```

My form:

```
class ToursForm(FlaskForm):
    customer_fname = StringField('Customer First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer_lname = StringField('Customer Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    customer_phone = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    partner_fname = StringField('Partner First Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    partner_lname = StringField('Partner Last Name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    partner_phone = StringField('Phone Number', validators=[DataRequired()])
    # tour_date = DateTimeField('Tour Date')
    tour_time = DateTimeField('Tour Time', format='%I:%M %p')
    gift = SelectField('Gift Selected', choices=[('Cruise', 'Cruise'), ('Hotel Suite', 'Hotel Suite'), ('Airfare', 'Airfare'), ('Safari', 'Safari')])
    region = SelectField('Region', choices=[('Select Region', 'Select Region'), ('Oceanside', 'Oceanside'), ('Scottsdale', 'Scottsdale'), ('Granite Bay', 'Granite Bay'), ('Laguna Hills', 'Laguna Hills')])
    submit = SubmitField('Add Tour')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with all the other fields, access `tour_time` field's data. Now you are passing the field itself as value.

```
tour_time=form.tour_time
```

should be

```
tour_time=form.tour_time.data
```

Comment: Dude... That's the craziest thing! .data WAS at the end, I swear it!! I have no idea why it's not there now, but this did indeed fix my issue. I poured over this for like an hour trying to figure it out. It's always something simple. Thanks again!